# AWX django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known

Tags: django, postgresql, ansible-awx

I have an AWX deployment using docker compose. The postgres database is having issues with dns name resolution. The issue started after I updated the docker-compose.yml to force the awx_web container to write some DNS IPs in /etc/resolv.conf. After that I ran:

> docker pull; docker compose up -d

The containers were recreated, and I could no longer connect to the AWX web interface. I have tried stopping the containers, restarting them, reloading nginx and confirm it's running, recreating the containers with tweaked docker-compose.yml's, and I keep running into the server error issue.

$ awx logs awx_web

```
 self.connect()
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known

RESULT 2
OKREADY
2023-03-15 02:16:01,844 INFO exited: wsbroadcast (exit status 1; not expected)
2023-03-15 02:16:01,844 INFO exited: wsbroadcast (exit status 1; not expected)
2023-03-15 02:16:02,848 INFO spawned: 'wsbroadcast' with pid 7561
2023-03-15 02:16:02,848 INFO spawned: 'wsbroadcast' with pid 7561
2023-03-15 02:16:03,850 INFO success: wsbroadcast entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2023-03-15 02:16:03,850 INFO success: wsbroadcast entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

post gres logs

```
PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization

2023-03-15 02:14:16.396 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2023-03-15 02:14:16.396 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2023-03-15 02:14:16.404 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-03-15 02:14:16.432 UTC [26] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-03-15 02:13:50 UTC
2023-03-15 02:14:16.440 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

```
NETWORK ID     NAME                 DRIVER    SCOPE
5c661c37460f   awxcompose_default   bridge    local
6e91f0243cfd   bridge               bridge    local
0f6ab0c7ce0f   host                 host      local
5c7e12dba410   none                 null      local
```

Going to the AWX home page shows this server error.

[image]

My docker-compose.yml

```
services:

  web:
    image: ansible/awx:15.0.0
    container_name: awx_web
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "80:8052"
      - "443:443"
    hostname: awxweb
    user: root
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - supervisor-socket:/var/run/supervisor
      - rsyslog-socket:/var/run/awx-rsyslog/
      - rsyslog-config:/var/lib/awx/rsyslog/
      - "~/.awx/awxcompose/SECRET_KEY:/etc/tower/SECRET_KEY"
      - "~/.awx/awxcompose/environment.sh:/etc/tower/conf.d/environment.sh"
      - "~/.awx/awxcompose/credentials.py:/etc/tower/conf.d/credentials.py"
      - "~/.awx/awxcompose/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro"
      - "~/.awx/awxcompose/redis_socket:/var/run/redis/:rw"
      - "/var/lib/awx/projects:/var/lib/awx/projects:rw"
      - "./resolv.conf:/etc/resolv.conf"  
    dns:
     - 127.0.0.11
    environment:
      http_proxy:
      https_proxy:
      no_proxy:

  task:
    image: ansible/awx:15.0.0
    container_name: awx_task
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - web
      - postgres
    command: /usr/bin/launch_awx_task.sh
    hostname: awx
    user: root
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - supervisor-socket:/var/run/supervisor
      - rsyslog-socket:/var/run/awx-rsyslog/
      - rsyslog-config:/var/lib/awx/rsyslog/
      - "~/.awx/awxcompose/SECRET_KEY:/etc/tower/SECRET_KEY"
      - "~/.awx/awxcompose/environment.sh:/etc/tower/conf.d/environment.sh"
      - "~/.awx/awxcompose/credentials.py:/etc/tower/conf.d/credentials.py"
      - "~/.awx/awxcompose/redis_socket:/var/run/redis/:rw"
      - "/var/lib/awx/projects:/var/lib/awx/projects:rw"
    dns:
      #- 10.1.2.3
      #- 10.2.3.4
       - 127.0.0.11
    environment:
      http_proxy:
      https_proxy:
      no_proxy:
      SUPERVISOR_WEB_CONFIG_PATH: '/etc/supervisord.conf'

  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: awx_redis
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      http_proxy:
      https_proxy:
      no_proxy:
    command: ["/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
    volumes:
      - "~/.awx/awxcompose/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf:ro"
      - "~/.awx/awxcompose/redis_socket:/var/run/redis/:rw"

  postgres:
    image: postgres:10
    container_name: awx_postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - "~/.awx/pgdocker/10/data/:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: awx
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: awxpass
      POSTGRES_DB: awx
      http_proxy:
      https_proxy:
      no_proxy:

volumes:
  supervisor-socket:
  rsyslog-socket:
  rsyslog-config:
```

I also tried redploying the environment using the awx/installer/install.yml, but the issue persists.

Comment: Look like the postgres container has failed. Can you post logs for the postgres container?

Comment: added, db listening